# Multiple slideshows not working (html, css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm supposed to have 4 different sliders with 3 different picture on each slider. I use W3school's slideshow (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple) to get the first two (which is working fine!) but when i tried to add 2 more the pictures won't show.

JS:

```
showSlides(1, 0);  <-- this was from W3
showSlides(1, 1);  <-- this was from W3
showSlides(1, 2);  <-- I added this
showSlides(1, 3);  <-- I added this
```

does someone know how to fix this problem?

Here is the one from W3Schools:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="grantoppen-slide">
    <img src="bilder/grantoppen01.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="grantoppen-slide">
    <img src="bilder/grantoppen02.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="grantoppen-slide">
    <img src="bilder/grantoppen03.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

And this is mine:

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1];
var slideId = ["grantoppen-slide", "granbo-slide", "granstua-slide", "granhaug-slide"];
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
showSlides(1, 3);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var bildeSlide = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > bildeSlide.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = bildeSlide.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < bildeSlide.length; i++) {
    bildeSlide[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  bildeSlide[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<p id="hyttenavn-slideshow"><i id="granstua-tekst">Granstua</i></p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="bilder/granstua01.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="bilder/granstua02.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="bilder/granstua03.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

**Solution 1:** the proper way would be to actually add 2 values to 'slideIndex':

```
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1, 1];
```

Instead of:

```
var slideIndex = [1, 1];
```

And that is it. This fixes the issue of the last line going out of index with new slides.

**Solution 2:** If you plan to change number of slides often and to automate it, you can populate the array for each index slide when page loads with an additional **initiaaliseSlides()** function:

```
var slideIndex = []; // This will be automatically populated
var slideId = ["grantoppen-slide", "granbo-slide", "granstua-slide", "granhaug-slide"];
initialiseSlides();
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2); // Note that this is set to 1 now
showSlides(1, 3);

// Initalise all starting slide indexes
function initialiseSlides(){
   for (var i = 0; i < slideId.length; i++){
      slideIndex[i] = 1;
   }
}

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

**Solution 3:** Or the showSlides() can be fixed up to correct itself like this, without using initialiseSlides(). Note the 4th line:

```
function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (typeof slideIndex[no] === 'undefined') {slideIndex[no] = 1;}
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: this worked and was so simple! Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Their JS they have seems to have backwards logic. The last line of JS`x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";` goes out of index and is the issue, and by using zero, the number of slides are set to correct index with the other line before that `if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}` which displays all the pictures and doesn't go out of index. It only changes the start position, and is a bug in their JS which is circumvented in a way without rewriting the function. Actually setting zero for all slides will work too, it just changes the starting slide to the last one.

Comment: @AadneHaaland, I stand corrected. There is a proper way which we missed. Please see a minor change in the edit of the answer. The slide Index keep track of multiple slide's current slides, value for which was not initialised and was making it go out of index.

Comment: @AadneHaaland, updated answer with proper solution for entire JS. It required to initiate slide number for each slide, which in your case were not added and that was the reason for slideIndex going out of index. By setting it to zero, it was getting assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Well your javascript was okay, except for the slideId array. As you gave only one slider in this example, the `granstua-slide`, that would have been the only one needed. However, as you asked about multiple sliders, I copied your code to make a second slider, but assigned a second class name, `granstua-img`, and added that to the array.

The plusSlides (-1, 0) ( to move back and forward) should remain the same as in the initial code, so you don't need to adjust these - that's where were going wrong regarding navigation

Hope this helps

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1];
var slideId = ["granstua-slide", "granstua-img"];

showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
showSlides(1, 3);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var bildeSlide = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > bildeSlide.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < bildeSlide.length; i++) {
     bildeSlide[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  bildeSlide[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.grantstua-slide {display: none};
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="hyttenavn-slideshow"><i id="granstua-tekst">Granstua</i></p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="granstua-slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p id="hyttenavn-slideshow"><i id="granstua-tekst">Slidehow 2</i></p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="granstua-img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="granstua-img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  
   <div class="granstua-img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```